# PySimpleGUI one_line_progress_meter does not return False when pressing X on Windows

Tags: python, user-interface, progress-bar, pysimplegui

In the [docs](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#progress-meters) of PySimpleGUI it is stated that the function returns true if either the cancel button is pressed or the X button in the windows titlebar. However, it is only working for the Cancel button in version 4.55.1.

MWE:

```
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

for i in range(1, 200):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if not sg.one_line_progress_meter(title="test", current_value=i, max_value=200,
                                      no_button=False):
        print('returned false')
        break
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation about pressing the X button.

Comment: @martineau In the link I've given the following is written for the return values: 
(bool) RETURN True if updated successfully. False if user closed the meter with the X or Cancel button. Do they mean the same button with both "Cancel" and "X"?

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right. Must be a bug, because not only does clicking on X button not cause the function to return `False`, it doesn't close the window either.

Comment: Another reason for posting problems on the PySimpleGUI GitHub....... an issue that exposes a problem such as this can then be tracked, indicated as something that requires action.  Otherwise, it's just sitting here, not being acted on..... I see that it's since been logged on GitHub... thank you for taking the time to ask there too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the window of `sg.one_line_progress_meter`, it is defined as `disable_close=True`, so this window cannot be closed by clicking `Close` button of window, Only `Cancel` button work for it.

OK, following code show the hack way

- Find the window for `one_line_progress_meter`
- Set the attribute `DisableClose` of quick-meter window to `False`

```py
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.one_line_progress_meter(title="test", current_value=0, max_value=200, no_button=False)
key='OK for 1 meter'
meter = sg.QuickMeter.active_meters[key]
meter.window.DisableClose = False

for i in range(1, 200):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if not sg.one_line_progress_meter(title="test", current_value=i, max_value=200, no_button=False):
        print('returned false')
        break

sg.one_line_progress_meter_cancel()
```

Comment: If that's how the window of `sg.one_line_progress_meter` is defined, then the documentation is *wrong*.

Comment: In Release Notes on https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, it says
4.29.0 PySimpleGUI 25-Aug-2020
Disable close on one_line_progress_meter. There is a cancel button that will close the window.

Comment: Martin, I think you're the person that opened the GitHub issue... if so THANK YOU so much for taking the time to do that.  It's so very helpful to the project!  Whoever opened it... thank you.

Comment: Post on github is about three days ago, but here just two days, IMO, the man should be Doesbaddel.

Comment: Most importantly in all this is that Jason has been HERE as well as on GitHub answering issues. Most projects are not so lucky. I'm a little puzzled by the double post. It'll be good to understand so that I can maybe make a change to our GitHub issues if needed.

Comment: Hello, I want to make my decisions more clear: At first I asked the question here. Unfortunately mattineau couldn't help me either and thought it's a bug (like I partially thought too after trying alot of things) that's why I opened the issue right after I've tried to get an answer here.(My name is also Martin.) Sorry for the double post!

Comment: @MikefromPSG No problem! Thank you guys too for creating this project. Without it, I probably wouldn't be able to create nice looking GUIs for my small Python projects.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.... was scratching my head on which Martin :-)  I'm happy you're happy.